# Problem 2 chapter 4 from baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $f$ is a continuous mapping of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$, prove that $$f(\overline{E})\subset \overline{f(E)}$$ for every set $E\subset X$. Show, by an an example, that $f(\overline{E})$ can be proper subset of $\overline{f(E)}$.

**Proof:** Let $y\in f(\overline{E})$ then exists $x\in \overline{E}$ s.t. $y=f(x)$. 
It's easy to check that $E\subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(E)})$ and the last set is closed because our mapping is continuous. Hence $\overline{E}\subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(E)})$ and $x\in \overline{E}$. Hence $x\in f^{-1}(\overline{f(E)})$. It means that $y=f(x)\in \overline{f(E)}$. Thus $f(\overline{E})\subset \overline{f(E)}$.

Taking $X=\mathbb{R^1}\setminus \{0\},Y=\mathbb{R^1},E=\mathbb{N}$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ which is continuous at $X$. We see that $\overline{f(E)}=\{0\}\cup \{\frac{1}{n}: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ but $f(\overline{E})=\{\frac{1}{n}: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Are my proof and example true?

Comment: To me your proof and your example are correct.

Comment: Did you really proved this problem by your own? That's insane. Now, I am reading Rudin book like you was in 2015. I can only dream of writing such a clever and slick proof.